# Finding Largest repeated letter between two columns a/o rows

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm

I try to find largest consecutive letter between two dynamic colums.
Below code find largest consequent letter below same column (like `C10:C50`) however I want to check different range like `"D13:D23;E9:E12"`. Below code brings me fault. Also can anyone help me to how I can convert it to row defined.

```
Function CountConsVal(r As Range)
    Dim i As Long, s As Long
    Rng = r.Value
    For i = LBound(Rng, 1) To UBound(Rng, 1) - 1
        If Rng(i, 1) = Rng(i + 1, 1) Then
            s = s + 1
            Rng(i, 1) = ""
        Else
            Rng(i, 1) = s + 1
            s = 0
        End If
    Next i
    Rng(UBound(Rng), 1) = s + 1
    CountConsVal = Rng
End Function
```

[image: rest & working table]

Comment: What is *"largest consequent letter between two dynamic colums"*? Can you give a more detailed description and can you give an example input and your desired output value as well? Also if you cut off the column letters from your screenshot your references get useless as we have no idea where in the image you refer to.

Comment: Consequent or consecutive? Did you choose the wrong word?

Comment: What do you want to get as input and output?

Comment: If e.g. in `A1:A6` there are `a, a, a, b, b, a`, `CountConsVal(Range("A1:A6")` will return a 2D one-based one-column array with `, , 3, , 2, 1`, the number of consecutive occurrences of each value at the index (position) of the last occurrence which could easily be written to a range with e.g. `Range("B1:B6").Value = CountConsVal(Range("A1:A6"))`. I can't see where you're using this in your worksheet?

Comment: I mean consecutive. The project aimed to find consecutive resting hours in any 24 hour period. (1 row contain 48 cell which represents 30 minute interval of day. Working time marked as w and resting time   marked as ' r'. And minimum consecutive resting hour must be equal or more than 6 hours)

Answer (score 1):

### Counting Consecutive Group Members

- This is the same function you provided a little more readable with some minor changes.

  ```
  Range("B1:B6").Value = GetGroupCountCols(Range("A1:A6"))
  ```

```vb
   A  B
1  a
2  a
3  a  3
4  b
5  b  2
6  c  1
```

```vb
Function GetGroupCountCols(ByVal rg As Range) As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cData As Variant
    If drCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim cData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cData(1, 1) = 1
    Else ' multiple cells
        cData = rg.Columns(1).Value ' ensure one column
        Dim r As Long, rCount As Long
        For r = 1 To drCount - 1
            If cData(r, 1) = cData(r + 1, 1) Then
                cData(r, 1) = Empty: rCount = rCount + 1
            Else
                cData(r, 1) = rCount + 1: rCount = 0
            End If
        Next r
        cData(drCount, 1) = rCount + 1
    End If
    
    GetGroupCountCols = cData
End Function
```

- This is the same function but for rows.

  ```
  Range("A2:F2").Value = GetGroupCountRows(Range("A1:F1"))
  ```

```vb
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1  a  a  a  b  b  c 
2        3     2  1
```

```vb
Function GetGroupCountRows(ByVal rg As Range) As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim rData As Variant
    If dcCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = 1
    Else ' multiple cells
        rData = rg.Rows(1).Value ' ensure one row
        Dim c As Long, cCount As Long
        For c = 1 To dcCount - 1
            If rData(1, c) = rData(1, c + 1) Then
                rData(1, c) = Empty: cCount = cCount + 1
            Else
                rData(1, c) = cCount + 1: cCount = 0
            End If
        Next c
        rData(1, dcCount) = cCount + 1
    End If
    
    GetGroupCountRows = rData
End Function
```

- This is a test for the following two functions:

```vb
Sub GetGroupColumnsCountTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("I10:I12,F4:F6,G7:G9")
    Debug.Print rg.Address
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetGroupColumnsCount(GetMultiColumns(rg))
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = Range("K4").Resize(UBound(Data, 1))
    rg2.Value = Data
End Sub
```

- This function will return the values of multiple column ranges in a 2D one-based one-column array.

  ```
  Range("F1:F6").Value = GetMultiColumns(Range("E6,A1:A3,C4:C5")) ' see previous procedure
  ```

```vb
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1  a              a    
2  a              a
3  b              b
4        c        c
5        c        c
6             d   d
```

```vb
Function GetMultiColumns(ByVal mrg As Range) As Variant
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Write data to a jagged array.
    Dim aCount As Long: aCount = mrg.Areas.Count
    Dim aData As Variant: ReDim aData(1 To aCount, 1 To 3)
    Dim Help As Variant: ReDim Help(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    Dim a As Long
    Dim arCount As Long, drCount As Long
    For a = 1 To aCount
        With mrg.Areas(a)
            aData(a, 1) = .Row
            aData(a, 2) = .Rows.Count
            drCount = drCount + aData(a, 2)
            If aData(a, 2) = 1 Then
                aData(a, 3) = Help: aData(a, 3)(1, 1) = .Value
            Else
                aData(a, 3) = .Value
            End If
        End With
    Next a
    
    ' Bubble sort the array by its first column (first rows) ascending.
    ReDim Help(1 To 1)
    Dim b As Long, c As Long
    For a = 1 To aCount - 1
        For b = a To aCount
            If aData(a, 1) > aData(b, 1) Then
                For c = 1 To 3
                    Help(1) = aData(a, c)
                    aData(a, c) = aData(b, c)
                    aData(b, c) = Help(1)
                Next c
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
    
    ' Write result.
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    Dim dr As Long
    For a = 1 To aCount
        Dim r As Long, rCount As Long
        For r = 1 To aData(a, 2)
            dr = dr + 1
            dData(dr, 1) = aData(a, 3)(r, 1)
        Next r
    Next a
    
    GetMultiColumns = dData
End Function
```

- This is the same as your function but it takes a 2D one-based one-column array instead of a one-column range as the argument.

```vb
Function GetGroupColumnsCount(ByVal sData As Variant) As Variant
    If IsEmpty(sData) Then Exit Function
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    Dim cData As Variant: ReDim cData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    If drCount = 1 Then
        cData(1, 1) = sData(1, 1)
    Else
        Dim r As Long, rCount As Long
        For r = 1 To drCount - 1
            If sData(r, 1) = sData(r + 1, 1) Then
                rCount = rCount + 1
            Else
                cData(r, 1) = rCount + 1: rCount = 0
            End If
        Next r
        cData(drCount, 1) = rCount + 1
    End If
    
    GetGroupColumnsCount = cData
End Function
```

- To conclude, the last two functions do what you primarily requested. The only job for you is to combine them into one if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to determine the maximum consecutive "r" values in each of many **rows**, one row at a time.

I suggest a User Defined Function with a one-row argument

- Optionally check that the range argument is valid
- read the range into a variant array for faster processing
- Use a dictionary to collect each consecutive group of `r`'s
- Iterate through the dictionary to find the longest
- Divide the final count by two to convert to hours
- I used early-binding for the Dictionary object, but you can use late-binding if you prefer. Early-binding may execute slightly faster.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'case insensitive
Function LongestConsecutiveRestingHrs(rw As Range) As Double
    Dim vRw As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim I As Long
    
    'Optional sanity check: eg:
    'confirm rw is 48 columns x 1 row
    'If Not rw.Rows.Count = 1 Or Not rw.Columns.Count = 48 Then
    '    MsgBox "Invalid Range: " & rw.Address & vbLf & "Please enter valid range"
    '    Exit Function
        
'read into variant array for faster processing
vRw = rw

'count consecutive "r" groups
Set dict = New Dictionary

I = 0
For Each v In vRw 'can do this since vRw will be a 1D array
    If v <> "r" Then
        I = I + 1
    Else
        dict(I) = dict(I) + 1
    End If
Next v

'find max r
I = 0
For Each v In dict.Keys
   I = IIf(I > dict(v), I, dict(v))
Next v

LongestConsecutiveRestingHrs = I / 2
   
End Function
```